# How to delete a foreign key from MySQL table dynamically?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to drop a foreign key from a table referencing a specified table. I don't know the name of the foreign key, I only know the table it is in and the table it references. This is what I got so far:

```
alter table tblTableWhereFKIs drop foreign key (select constraint_name 
from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where referenced_table_name = 'tblReferencedByFK' and table_name = 'tblTableWhereFKIs' limit 1);
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select constraint_name
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where referen' at line 1
```

The select alone works:

```
mysql> select constraint_name
    -> from information_schema.key_column_usage
    -> where referenced_table_name = 'tblReferencedByFK' and table_name = 'tblTableWhereFKIs' limit 1;
+-----------------------------------------+
| constraint_name                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
| fk_tblTableWhereFKIs_tblReferencedByFK1 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that.  The alter statement doesn't know how to extrapolate the results from your select into multiple executions of drop foreign key.

I usually do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('alter table ', table_name, ' drop foreign key ', constraint_name, ';')
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE referenced_table_name = 'tblReferencedByFK' and table_name = 'tblTableWhereFKIs';
```

I execute the above query which will build all the alter statements for me.  I then take that list of alter statements and run them manually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have mySQL to hand so can't test this, but I think something along the lines of the following will work:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)

SELECT  @SQL = 'alter table tblTableWhereFKIs drop foreign key ' + constraint_name
FROM    information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE   referenced_table_name = 'tblReferencedByFK' 
AND     table_name = 'tblTableWhereFKIs'

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL
EXECUTE stmt
```

My experience of MySQL is limited so this is a mixture of your answer and information from the [MySQL Website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)